# Using AWS S3 and Apache Spark with hdf5/netcdf-4 data

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, boto, hdf5, netcdf

I've got a bunch of atmospheric data stored in AWS S3 that I want to analyze with Apache Spark, but am having a lot of trouble getting it loaded and into an RDD. I've been able to find examples online to help with discrete aspects of the problem:

-using h5py to read ***locally stored*** scientific data files via `h5py.File(filename)` (https://hdfgroup.org/wp/2015/03/from-hdf5-datasets-to-apache-spark-rdds/)

-boto/boto3 to get data that is ***textfile*** format from S3 into Spark via `get_contents_as_string()`

-map a set of text files to an RDD via `keys.flatMap(mapFunc)`

But I can't seem to get these parts to work together. Specifically-- how do you load in a netcdf file from s3 (using boto or directly, not attached to using boto) in order to then use h5py? Or can you treat the netcdf file as a binary file and load it in as a binary file and map to an rdd using `sc.BinaryFile(binaryFile)`?

Here's a couple of similar questions that weren't answered fully that relate:

[How to read binary file on S3 using boto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955662/how-to-read-binary-file-on-s3-using-boto)

[using pyspark, read/write 2D images on hadoop file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731140/using-pyspark-read-write-2d-images-on-hadoop-file-system/28753276#28753276)

Comment: _can you treat the netcdf file as a binary file and load it in as a binary file_ - as far as I know the answer is negative. `hpy5` uses C client directly and doesn't support buffers (`BytesIO`). S3Fs hassle-free `get` which can be used to copy from S3 to a local file system and then accesses with `h5py`.

Comment: thanks @zero323, looking up the s3fs interface

Answer (score 1):

Using the `netCDF4` and `s3fs` modules, you can do:

```py
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

filename = 's3://bucket/a_file.nc'
with s3.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    nc_bytes = f.read()

root = Dataset(f'inmemory.nc', memory=nc_bytes)
```

Make sure you are setup to read from S3. For details, [here](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#section15) is the documentation.